# Which plugins can I use to print HTML code?

Tags: c#, .net, html

I have some HTML code to show up on an HTML page, so it must not be interpreted as HTML.
Also, I'd like to maintain space/empty line and so on.

I'm on C#/.NET 3.5 : what can I use?

Comment: I am sure there are similar questions. Did you check related questions?

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin"? Plugin to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not actually saying *which* technology within .Net you are using to render your Html page (Asp.Net WebForms or MVC or whatever) the answer falls back to how you would do it in HTML, regardless of your server technology.  After that, how you actually achieve this output is entirely up to you.

Render it in a `<pre />` block:

```
<pre>
  &lt;p&gt;hello world!&lt;/p&gt;
<pre>
```

Here the text will appear as `<p>Hello world!</p>` and, by default, appear in a fixed-width font and all whitespace will be retained.

Comment: And don't forget to replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;

Comment: @CFL_Jeff - yep just realised my mistake!  Crumbs I better go back to school :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx).

> Encodes a string to be displayed in a browser.

And documented in the overloads:

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings **`&lt;`** and **`&gt;`**, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

It is not clear for what purpose you want to display this, but you may want to [pretty print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint) before HTML encoding (the HTML Agility Pack may do this, not sure) - and to show it as fixed width you can enclose in a `<pre>` element.